# Is the following code reentrant and thread-safe?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, thread-safety, reentrancy

Is the following code is reentrant?

Is it thread-safe, if `this.NextToExecuteIndex` is declared `private int NextToExecuteIndex = 0;` and not computed anywhere else?

```
    protected override void Poll(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        int index;

        object locker = new object();

        lock (locker)
        {
            Interlocked.Increment(ref this.NextToExecuteIndex);

            if (this.NextToExecuteIndex >= this.ReportingAgentsTypes.Count())
            {
                this.NextToExecuteIndex = 0;
            }

            index = this.NextToExecuteIndex;
        }

        var t = this.ReportingAgentsTypes[index];

        Console.WriteLine(t.ToString());
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No this is not thread-safe at all. The lock has no effect since the object is local to the thread. It needs to be shared by all calling threads. Once you fix that you don't need to use interlocked increment because the lock serialises execution.

As a general rule you should place `locker` at the same level as the resource you are protecting. If the resource is owned by the instance then so should be `locker`. Similarly if the resource is owned by the class.

As for re-entrancy, the `lock` keyword uses a re-entrant lock, i.e. one that lets the same thread in if the lock is held by that thread. That's probably not what you want. But if you had a non re-entrant lock then you would just deadlock yourself with a re-entrant call. And I don't think you'd want that either.

You look like you want a wrap around increment. So long as the collection is not being modified, this can be achieved with interlocked operations, i.e. lock free. If so then it can be written like this:

```
do
{
    int original = this.NextToExecuteIndex;
    int next = original+1;
    if (next == this.ReportingAgentsTypes.Count())
        next = 0;
}
while (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref this.NextToExecuteIndex, next, original) != original);
```

**Note:** You should declare `NextToExecuteIndex` as volatile.

Comment: Thanks, I suspected declaring the `locker` object in local scope was not good idea, however I now undertand why! =) `Poll` is called once per thread. I've moved the `locker` object as an instance private variable. However reading your answer I wonder if this is OK, since the thread is created in Poll's class's base class, (sorry for the double saxon genitive, sounds awful!) being Poll an override of the an abstract method in the base class? So is it OK that `locker` is not accessible in the base class scope, which is where the threads are created? Many thanks.

Comment: Thanks David, reading your last two lines in your comment ("You look like you want to wrap..."), how can I change it then so that the check and reset-to-0 is all done in an atomic operation. The best that I can come up with is `if(Interlocked.Increment(ref this.NextToExecuteIndex) >= this.ReportingAgentsTypes.Count()){this.NextToExecuteIndex = 0; }` but by the time the code enters the `if` body, `NextToExecuteIndex` may have changed! Many Thanks.

Comment: Comment 1: What you've done sounds fine. An instance is made up of the base class and the derived classes. It's still the same object. No problems there. Comment 2: You need compare and swap, as I have edited the answer to show.

Answer (score 4):

Absolutely not. This is your problem `object locker = new object();`. You will create a new object and lock on it every time.